# Starting Javascript on PHP Based time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, colors

I have multiple HTML/PHP/JavaScript pages, a JavaScript code blinks 2 colors, (Black and White). If Page 1 is black, can the other pages be black, when it blinks white, all the other pages are white? (So there is 1 timer running multiple pages?) Execute JS script on PHP Clock (Seconds maybe?) I am on a linux webhost. Can the other pages wait for the first cycle on that JS page to be completed before starting their event etc.?

[Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/LbquCgPM)

```
-1.txt/2.txt has: #000000 (Colors)
```

*Sorry don't know how to use tags and stuff, pretty new.

Comment: sounds like the most annoying UI ever

Comment: I'm not sure this will work if the time is generated on the server.  There will be a delay while you download and display the page on the client side.  The delay will not be the same for all clients, so it will be hard to synchronize everything.

Comment: I agree PHP is executed on the server, you could send the value to JavaScript and then call a time out.